# Is it possible to use ob_get_contents but keep php balise?

Tags: php, ob-get-contents

Is it possible to use ob_get_contents but keep php balise?

**Code:**

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php echo 'asdfasdf'; ?>
<?php 
   $content = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
?>
```

**Result:**

```
<?php echo 'asdfasdf'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want a [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
echo <<<'STR'
<?php echo 'asdfasdf'; ?>
STR;
```